# jquery autocomplete for shops near location

Tags: php, jquery, geolocation, google-api

I've got a list of shops that I have put in a javascript array. I have their addresses as well.

I'm needing to create an autocomplete which allows me to put in a city name and it displays the 3 nearest to that location. I imagine it will need to interface with google's apis some how but not sure where to start.

I've got the actual autocomplete jquery stuff working on an ajax script, but I don't know how to get things located nearest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the lat/long locations of the stores, https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/ Then you need the lat/long location of the user, with some relatively simple mathematics you can then calculate the distance between these two points:

```
$distance = round((6371*3.1415926*sqrt(($lat2-$lat1)*($lat2-$lat1) + 
cos($lat2/57.29578)*cos($lat1/57.29578)*($lon2-$lon1)*($lon2-$lon1))/180), 1);
```

If you have a large number of stores and a large number of users I advise caching these distances in a mysql table, you have to do this for each store in your database. So you create a table for each e.g. zipcode that requests this and put up a cron to remove these tables every hour or so.

So the process:

1. User asks for the nearest store
2. You get his location through google api (or your own storage)
3. Check if there's a table for his location
4. If yes, give him the results directly, if no generate the table and give him the results

Mind that google only allows a limited number of data requests. Even though this number is huge (I believe 25.000 requests per day) it may be advisable to store the lat-lon locations of your stores AND users. Would also improve the speed.

I made something similar to this, I fetched the lat/lon locations at the moment a location was inserted into the database and inserted it in a seperate per-zipcode lat/lon table.